# Norms on $M_n(A)$ where A is a unital C* algebra.

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras, operator-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space,and let $(a_{i,j})$ be in $M_n(B(H))$. Prove that $\|(a_{i,j})\|\leq(\sum_{i,j}\|a_{i,j}\|^2)^{1/2} \leq n\|(a_{i,j})\|$.

By definition $\|(a_{i,j})\|^2=sup \{\|(a_{i,j})(h_j)\|^2: \|(h_j)\|^2\leq1, (h_j)\in H^{\oplus n}\}
=sup \{\|(\sum_ja_{i,j}h_j)\|^2: \|(h_j)\|^2\leq1, (h_j)\in H^{\oplus n}\}=sup \{\sum_i\|\sum_ja_{i,j}h_j\|^2: \|(h_j)\|^2\leq1, (h_j)\in H^{\oplus n}\}\leq sup \{\sum_i(\sum_j\|a_{i,j}h_j\|)^2: \|(h_j)\|^2\leq1, (h_j)\in H^{\oplus n}\}$.  (by triangle inequality)

$=sup \{\sum_i(\sum_j\|a_{i,j}\|^2)(\sum_j\|h_j\|^2): \|(h_j)\|^2\leq1, (h_j)\in H^{\oplus n}\}$ (by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality)
$=\sum_{i,j}\|a_{i,j}\|^2.$

Hence $\|(a_{i,j})\|\leq(\sum_{i,j}\|a_{i,j}\|^2)^{1/2}$

How to show the right-hand side inequality? This result will imply that if $\phi:B(H)\mapsto B(H)$ is bounded, then $\phi_n:M_n(B(H))\mapsto M_n(B(H))$ defined by $\phi_n((a_{i,j}))=(\phi(a_{i,j}))$ is also bounded and $\|\phi_n\|\leq n\|\phi\|.$

Comment: What does the notation $||(a_{i,j})||$ mean?

Comment: Seems relevant: $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}\leq\|\cdot\|_1\leq n\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ for norms on $\mathbb{R}^n$ ([Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Relations_between_p-norms)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a mistake in your argument, you wrote as an equality the step where you are using Cauchy-Schwarz (which you don't mention either).

As for the other inequality, the proof is exactly the same as the better known case (where $\dim H=1$). I'll write $A$ for the matrix. You always have
$$
\|a_{ij}\|\leq\|A\|.
$$
Then
\begin{align}
\sum_i\sum_j\|a_{ij}\|^2\leq\sum_{i,j}\|A\|^2=n^2\|A\|^2. 
\end{align}

Comment: How did you get $||a_{ij}||\le ||A||$? Here, $||A||$ is the "operator norm" of $A\in \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H} \oplus \dots \oplus \mathcal{H})$ ($n$ times) ...In case of $H=\Bbb{C}$ then I can write $||A||\ge ||A(0,\dots,1, \dots, 0)||\ge ||a_{ij}||$ for all $i, j$..But how to prove that for general case?

Comment: Here I am assuming $||A||=\sup\{||Ax||~:~x\in \mathcal{H}^{\oplus n},||x||=1\}$ where $||(x_1,\dots, x_n)||^2:=\sum_{i}||x_i||^2$

Comment: $$|a_{kj}|=|\langle Ae_j,e_k\rangle|\leq\|Ae_j\|\,\|e_k\|\leq\|A\|\,\|e_j\|\,\|e_k\|=\|A\|.$$

Comment: I'm actually confused because here $a_{ij}$'s are in $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$...

Comment: Okay does this follow as: $||a_{ij}||=||V_i A U_j||\le||A||$ where $U_j:\mathcal{H}\to\mathcal{H}^{\oplus n}$ is $U_jx:=(0,\dots,x,\dots,0)$ and $V_j:\mathcal{H}^{\oplus n}\to \mathcal{H}$ is $V_j(x_1,\dots,x_n):=x_j$ then $||U_j||\le 1$ and $||V_j||\le 1$...Is this right also?

Comment: Yes, you are right. What I wrote works for the scalar case, and it generalizes as you say.

Comment: Thank you so much